# Rails How to Use Include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following:

```
@comments = @message.comments.roots.order("created_at DESC")
```

This gets all the the comments for a particular message.

Later in the page I run several:

```
comment.user.profile_pic.url(:small)
```

The problem with this is that the save user query is hitting the database over and over.

```
User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 3) LIMIT 1
```

I'm curious to learn how I can use include to eager load the user info along with the comments above. I tried:

```
@comments = @message.comments.include(:users).roots.order("created_at DESC")
```

Suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a Comment has only one User, you might try `.includes(:user)`

Comment: also, includes ends in an 's' because `include` is already used for mixins